# Exporting in Netsuite

Tags: export-to-csv, netsuite

One of our customer's uses Netsuite ERP. We would like to be able accept pick tickets(orders) from them in a format that would allow us to import the pick tickets into our custom built ERP system. Naturally, I asked them if they could export the pick tickets as CSV to us.

They are attempting to build a custom report with all the fields we need and export it into csv. Aside from them having issues exporting the report only to HTML... Im curious as to why they cant just export the pick ticket they have been sending us, which is in pdf format.

On top of that. Ive noticed via SuitesScript you could modify the on click event to generate a csv of the data. So when they click generate print ticket, why could it not easily generate a csv at that time?

Basically, due to me not havign hands on to their NetSuite system - or any insight to the inner working of NetSuite, im looking to the community to explain to me, what they are doing wrong - or what the best solution is to attain the goal of: exporting a pick ticket(im assuming this is based from the sales order in netsuite...) in a friendly format, allowing me to automate the order entry into my company's system.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure Netsuite provides CSV option for exporting Reports. Please refer to this [doc](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteAnalyticsDashboardsSearchesReports/Reports/ExportingReport.html).

> To export a report:
>
> 1. On the Reports page, click the name of the report you want to see.
> 2. In the footer of the report, select Export-CSV, Export-Microsoft® Word, Export-Microsoft® Excel, or Export-PDF.

One possible problem may be the Role Permissions. Please refer to [this](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteAnalyticsDashboardsSearchesReports/Search/ExportingSearchResults.html).

> If your search results pages do not include an Export button, your account administrator may not have assigned you the Full level for the Perform Search permission. This level is required for exporting search results. The Export Lists permission also is required. See [Permissions for Searches](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteAnalyticsDashboardsSearchesReports/Search/PermissionsSearches.html).

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to export pdf. Please refer to https://github.com/eliseobeltran/NSProject/blob/314c5a03c4251cd06d451527103b7b85bb63f130/GOP/Innov.GOP.GeneratePDF.js

Comment: They currently export pick tickets as a .pdf. Im wondering why they couldnt export to a CSV or XML instead of pdf.

Answer (score -1):

Once you create the saved search, NetSuite has the option to export the saved search as the CSV, MS EXCEL, or PDF. But it's a manual approach. You can do it automatically by writing a JavaScript script in the Suite Script.